# Union of two sorted lists via Java Collections API basic methods

Tags: java

So I need two methods that compute the union and intersection of two sorted lists of comparable items. I have the intersection code finished and you can see it below, I am using binary search to accomplish this. But I am kind of stuck on the union part of the problem, not really sure how to tackle it, any ideas or help?

```
public class UnionAndIntersection {

public static <X extends Comparable<? super X>> void intersection(List<X> L1, List<X> L2, List<X> result) {
    boolean found;    
    X number;
    X prev = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < L1.size(); i++) {
        number = L1.get(i);
        found = binarySearch(L2, number);

        if (found == true && prev != number) {
            result.add(number);
            prev = number;
        }
    }
}

public static <X extends Comparable<? super X>> void union(List<X> L1, List<X> L2, List<X> result) {

}    

public static <X extends Comparable<? super X>> boolean binarySearch(List<X> allNumbers, X number, int first, int last) {
    if (first > last) {
        return false;
    } else {
        int middle = (first + last) / 2;
        int compResult = number.compareTo(allNumbers.get(middle));

        if (compResult == 0) {
            return true;
        } else if (compResult < 0)
        {
            return binarySearch(allNumbers, number, first, middle - 1);
        } else
        {
            return binarySearch(allNumbers, number, middle + 1, last);
        }
    }
}

public static <X extends Comparable<? super X>> boolean binarySearch(List<X> allNumbers, X number) {
    return binarySearch(allNumbers, number, 0, allNumbers.size() - 1);
}

public static void display(List list) {
    for (Object object : list) {
        System.out.print(object + " ");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> L1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> L2 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> result1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> result2 = new ArrayList<>();
    L1.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
    L2.addAll(Arrays.asList(2, 4, 6, 8, 10));
    intersection(L1, L2, result1);
    System.out.print("Intersection of the two lists is: ");
    display(result1);
    System.out.print("\n");
    union(L1, L2, result2);        
    System.out.print("Union of the two lists is: ");        
    display(result2);
}
}
```

Comment: you can use java inbuilts like addall to do this

Comment: yea you did the intersection because someone showed and now you are "stuck" on union haha ...........

Answer (score 0):

If we are trying to use the same code for union also, we can try as below code. Union is complete set of L1 and L2 without duplicates, so we can add L1 and then when adding L2 we need to check whether that is already present in the result and then add it to the result.(assumption is there is no duplicates within the list).

```
public static <X extends Comparable<? super X>> void union(List<X> L1, List<X> L2, List<X> result) {


    boolean found;    
    X number;
    X prev = null;

for (int i = 0; i < L1.size(); i++) {
        result.add(L1.get(i));
}
for (int i=0; i<L2.size();i++){
       number = L2.get(i);
        found = binarySearch(L1, number);

        if (found == false ) {
            result.add(number);
        }
}

}
```